# Why is JS redis looping more times after succesful write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have the following logic for reading and writing redis state

```
export async function updateRedis() {
let stateName = 'stateName'
try {
    let isSuccess = false
    while (!isSuccess) {
        try {
            await redis
                .watch(stateName, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(`Error in watch state: ${err}`)
                    }
                    redis.get(stateName, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            logger.error(`Error in get state: ${err}`)
                        }

                        let state = JSON.parse(result)
                        // do some processing
                        redis.multi()
                            .set(stateName, JSON.stringify(state))
                            .exec(function (err, result) {
                                if (err) {
                                    logger.error(`Error in set state: ${err}`)
                                }
                                if (result != null) {
                                    isSuccess = true
                                }
                            })
                        console.log(`isSuccess for ${stateName} `, isSuccess)
                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error(`Error: ${e}`)
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    logger.error(`Error: ${e}`)
}
return Promise.resolve(true)
```

}

This will print out

```
"isSuccess for stateName false"
"isSuccess for stateName true"
"isSuccess for stateName true"
```

So after the flag changes to true, it will continue for more loops. Sometimes it does more than just once.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix a synchronous loop (`while (!isSuccess) { ... }`) with asynchronous functions (`redis.watch(stateName, function (err) { ... })`).

You can also not `await` callback-based asynchronous functions. A function *must* return a promise to be awaitable. Since node-redis gives you promises when you don't pass callbacks to its methods, the key is not to do that (`redis.watch(stateName, function (err) { ... })` → `redis.watch(stateName)`).

Your approach needs to be redone.

Let's make a function that encapsulates a [redis transaction with optimistic locking](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#optimistic-locking-using-check-and-set). It takes a connection object, a key, and a value-transforming function, and it returns the result of the `.set()` operation:

```
const redisTransaction = async (client, key, transformer) => {
    // https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/isolated-execution.md
    return client.executeIsolated(async isolatedClient => {
        await isolatedClient.watch(key);
        const val = await isolatedClient.get(key);
        return isolatedClient.multi()
            .set(key, await transformer.call(isolatedClient, val))
            .exec();
    });
};
```

Now you can `await` this function, because it returns a promise. That means we can make a simple infinite loop that exits immediately in case of success (via `return`), or retries indefinitely.

```
export async function updateRedis(key, transformer) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return await redisTransaction(redis, key, transformer);
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(`Error for state ${key}: ${err}`);
        }
    }
}
```

A transformer function takes a value, and returns a new value. Inside it, the `this` keyword refers to the `isolatedClient` from the transaction, which could be useful if your transformation depends on other values from that client.

```
const result = await updateRedis('stateName', async function (val) {
    const state = JSON.parse(val);
    const newState = await modifyStateSomehow(state);
    return JSON.stringify(newState);
});
```

The `modifyStateSomehow()` can itself be an asynchronous (i.e. "promise-returning") function. If it's not, you can make the state transformer a regular function by removing the `async` and the `await`.

Comment: great, its working. thanks very much